# set meta-date in manifest only for SDK>=21

Tags: android

I want to add meta-data tag to android manifest in my app.
I want this tag to be apply only to SDK>= 21.

Their is property to put in the meta-tag to apply this?

```
 <meta-data minSDK=21 />
```

Or their is another solution for this? I must make in in the manifest file cause this is the only file that I can edit.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand, this is your app but you can only edit the manifest ?

Comment: I have to change only the manifest...